# Preposition "by": used to show the degree or amount of something

Tags: prepositions

A definition of "by" from a dictionary:

> used to show the degree or amount of something
>
> - *The bullet missed him by two inches.*
> - *House prices went up by 10%*
> - *It would be better by far* (= much better) *to...*

I composed this sentence with meaning of by as shown above.

> I need you to pull shipping date in early by any day.

What I am conveying by this sentence is...;

I need you to ship the goods earlier than your already confirmed date(e.g. 10-Oct-2021).
pulling the current ship date in earlier by one day or two days would be nice.

That's what I am trying to say by my composed sentence.
But I am not sure that my sentence is right.

Comment: Your sentence doesn't work, but it would be possible to say _I need you to advance the shipping date by one or two days_.

Comment: Thank you, your feedback is what I want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"By" likes specifics. When you're dealing with a large area before, you need more wiggle room, you need a more general preposition than "by", so I would use "before":

> I need you to pull the shipping date any day before 10-Oct, 2021

**Important Note:** Add "a" or "the" before "shipping date": "I need you to pull *the* shipping date any before 10-Oct, 2021."

In English, err on the side of using "a" or "the" before a noun until you know not to.

Having an "a", "an", or a "the" where you shouldn't (it's hard to give an example) is a better mistake (to me) than missing it when you should have it.

Comment: This is all true, but it isn't the sense of _by_ that the OP was asking about.

Comment: @KateBunting "earlier than" means "before". To get me to agree with you, I'd need an example or a metaphor of how it's not.

Comment: The definition shown in the question refers to _missing by inches_ etc., not _doing something by a certain date_, which is a different sense of _by_. As I suggested above, they could have said _bring the date forward by two days_.

Comment: Those were examples for the OP to understand "by". His intent for use follows these examples.

Comment: Please note the title of the question!

Comment: Please read the actual question! "What I am conveying by this sentence is..."

Comment: Please calm down, guys. I am trying to say to pull the shipping date by any times, hours, days, or something.

Comment: So I think Kate Bunting exactly pointed out what I want to know. But I am also thankful to Aaron Bell. However I couldn't understand what you mean by that - In English, err on the side of using "a" or "the" before a noun until you know not to. - What is "err"? and What is "until you know not to?".....